# Dynamic select option list resetting to first value

Tags: javascript, html-select

I've got a dynamically populated `<select>` list, where the first option is created by HTML and PHP when the page first loads, but when you drop down, javascript populates a list of additional options. However, when I select an option and remove focus, it is reset to the original selected option. I'm pretty sure that what I'm doing is not getting saved, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Here's the HTML, which works fine:

```
<select name="select1" id="select1" onfocus= "checkSelect(this.value)">
<option value ="XXX">XXX</option>
</select>
```

The `checkSelect()` function does a bunch of stuff, but then it ends as follows:

```
//do a bunch of stuff, ending in populating the 'legal' array. 

document.input_form.select1.options.length=1; 
//which I think is actually redundant

for (i=0; i < legal.length; i++)
    {
        document.input_form.select1.options[i+1]=new 
        Option(legal[i], legal[i], false, false);
    }
```

Am I missing something necessary to make the option persist on the page?

Comment: Could be a problem with setting the contents of the SELECT as it's been focussed. Couldn't you populate the SELECT before then, when the page loads for example, see if that works?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The content of the SELECT can change based on other entries in the same form.

Comment: Hmm... Try this: onfocus, populate the ```<SELECT>``` (as you are doing already) then ```blur()``` to lose focus, then ```focus()``` on the ```<SELECT>``` again. Sounds silly I know, but it might help! (I've run into a similar problem on iOS before.)

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I could think of such a behavior would be `select1` wrapped into unclosed tag `<label>`, for example:

```
<label>label <!--may be missing </label> here -->
    <select name="select1" id="select1" onfocus="checkSelect(this.value)">      
        <option value ="XXX">XXX</option>
    </select> <!--may be missing </label> here -->
```